# Removing hashmap key from an object

Tags: java

```
HashMap<String, String> user= new HashMap<String, String>();
user.put("userID","1");
user.put("useValue", "false");
```

I have a hashMap with these `keys` and `values`.

```
Patient filterList = new Patient();
filterList.setUser(user);
```

Now i create another instance of Patient Class.

```
Patient addRequest = new Patient();
user.remove("useValue");
addRequest.setUser(user);
```

Why is that it gets removed from both the objects?. Though i am removing the key only after the filterList object is formed completely.

Answer (score 3):

Both objects `(filterList.setUser(user);)` and  `addRequest.setUser(user);`  pointing to same object, so changes are effective on same object.

`setUser(...)` doesn't really create a copy. It just sets the reference to user object.

If you observe carefully, in both cases the reference is user and pointing to same object created at `HashMap<String, String> user= new HashMap<String, String>();`

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting the `map` in your class, you are `not creating a new copy` of your map. Rather a `copy of reference` is created in that class `pointing to the same` `HashMap` object. So any change you make to the `Map` using any reference, will get reflected for `all the references`.

So, all the references - `user`, the one in `filterList.setUser` and `addRequest.setUser` are pointing to the same `HashMap` object.

Comment: private HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>(); should i do something like this in my class

Answer (score 1):

There is only one hashmap object in your example.

```
HashMap<String, String> user= new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Both the objects filterList and addRequest is depending on a single user object. So if you make any changes to the user object it will affect both filterList and addRequest.

If you dont want the change to be reflected in both filterList and addRequest then create two hashmap objects

```
    HashMap<String, String> user1= new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> user2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    user1.put("userID","1");
    user1.put("useValue", "a");
    user2 =  (HashMap<String, String>)user1.clone();
    user1.remove("userID");
    System.out.println(user2.get("userID"));
    System.out.println(user1.get("userID"));
```

Hope this helps..